# Upgrade to latest version of Express

Tags: express, npm

What is the command to get the latest version of Express which is already installed? What is the command to upgrade to latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the latest version to your production dependencies, you can simply run `npm i express@latest --save`. Whereas, to update the version globally, use `npm i express@latest -g`.

Comment: If I installed express locally then what is command to upgrade to latest version ?

Comment: What do you mean by locally? Do you mean dev dependency ?

Comment: Yes...dev dependency

Comment: You should use npm i express@latest --save-dev

Comment: FYI, if you want to require the package within your project, you should install it locally using either of npm i express@latest --save (This saves to production dependencies) or npm i express@latest --save-dev (This saves to dev dependencies).  If you want to run express on command line, you should install it globally using npm i express@latest -g