# Express JS not updating version in terminal

Tags: express, npm

I needed ExpressJS v 4.17 instead of 4.16 as it caused some dependency issues with other modules. I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727643/upgrade-to-latest-version-of-express) and now I can’t work out what’s going on.

In my package.json I’m seeing v 4.17 but when I try `express -v` in terminal I see 4.16. If I go to node modules in the directory my app is in the package.json for the express module is also 4.17 - but terminal still showing 4.16

Am I missing a step here? It looks like 4.16 is still installed according to terminal and that it hasn’t been updated despite all the other signs saying it has?

Comment: Did you update using the `-g` flag? Which versions of `express` are listed in the output  of `npm list` and `npm list -g`?

Comment: I did yes - when I use those commands from the directory of my app they both show 4.17.3

Comment: using npm list-g shows 'express-generator' as 4.16.1? Should that be the same as express itself?

Comment: so when I use command 'express --version' it is showing me the version of the express-generator and not express itself - is that meant to happen?

Comment: `express-generator` is the CLI component of Express - a cursory Google indicates that [its latest version on NPM is indeed `4.16.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator). Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that invoking express via the command line this way indicates in any way that `express`' core has not been updated, especially if `express`' version in `npm list [-g]` indicates otherwise?

Comment: As a follow-up, on a fresh system, running `npm install express -g` does not install any `express` binary into PATH, thus `express --version` on the same command line fails. However installing `express-generator` yields the `express` binary. Thus the command `express --version` is indicative **only of the `express-generator`** version you have installed, ***not*** the core of `express` itself.

Comment: thank you - sorry new to this this is a great explanation thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `express` on the command line invokes the functionality provided by `express-generator` (if you have it installed). Any output from this program would be specific to `express-generator` and *not* to `express` itself.

What you're seeing is the version of `express-generator` that's installed on your system, *not* the core of `express` itself. Use the output of `npm list [-g]` to discern what version of "core" Express is installed on your system or in your project.